# arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb versus gdb-multiarch

Tags: gcc, gdb, arm, embedded-linux

I'm trying to perform cross platform remote debugging from my x86 computer to a remote ARM device. (ex: Beagle Bone Black)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse CDT.

I installed the package **gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf** but the gdb debugger is not in that package. (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf)

Therefore, I'm wondering if I should use the Linaro toolchain (which include **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb**) or if I should install the **gdb-multiarch** package.

What is the difference between gdb-multiarch and arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb ?
Is it better to use gdb-multiarch ?

ssinfod

Answer (score 13):

I received an answer from the linaro mailing list:

For Ubuntu hosts from 12.04 onwards, gdb-multiarch is used as gdb client for debugging. As name indicates it is a common client to any architecture and not restricted to ARM.

Generally, all gdb clients are architecture independent because architecture specific part is handled in gdbserver itself. So, other than the name arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb, I am guessing it is same as gdb-multiarch.

Answer (score 3):

I received another answer from the linaro mailing list:

The Linaro gdb release will generally be more up to date than the
Ubuntu one. For example our latest release is 7.8, and that is only
available in utopic, not trusty so if you plan to use an Ubuntu LTS
release it might be better to use the Linaro shipped gdb. Linaro gdb
also contains fixes and improvements that aren't in the upstream
stable branch. Historically Ubuntu has often picked these changes up
too but that may not always be the case.

gdb-multiarch obviously supports a range of other architectures
besides ARM, so if that is something that would be useful for you then
it might make sense to use that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, was not sure indeed whats the difference between a gdb provided by a distro and Linaro one. As both are clients, and on first observation I could debug by ARM target with the pre-installed gdb client.